# command to start websphere from IBM RAD

Tags: command, publish, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

In my project, it takes a lot of time to take the latest source code from svn, build and publish it on the IBM Websphere server. The IDE we are using is IBM RAD.

So I was working to automate this whole task, so that I dont have to waste my time in morning. So far I am able to get the source, build it in rad using ant screipt. Now the pending items are starting the server in debug mode and publishing the compiled code. I looked almost everywhere [may be not at right place :( ]. So anyone here have an idea which commands to use to achieve the above pending items.

Thanks,

Hanumant.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to do this.

A lot of us use hudson/jenkins etc t pull out the source code from SVN, run the ant/maven based scripts to build and publish to a WAS Server.

Look at the various articles in this space. A quick google throws me a number of results

A couple of examples are:

1. http://bikedreamer.blogspot.com/2009/11/websphere-automated-deployment-on.html
2. http://lresende.blogspot.com/2008/02/automating-websphere-with-maven-and.html

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Hi @Manglu, Thanks for the links. Actually what I am looking is to publish the compiled source code from RAD to webshpere server (i.e. the actions called when we click run -> debug, server -> publish etc in RAD IDE). The links describe the steps to automate deployment on server and that I have already setup in our integration server using the ant scripts.